# Pervasive v10 query syntax error

Tags: pervasive, pervasive-sql

I have a query`SELECT WOBOM_ASSY FROM WOBOM WHERE WOBOM_LINE^ = ? AND WOBOM_WOPRE = ? AND WOBOM_WOSUF = ?`
But I have "WOBOM_LINE^<> Syntax Error". I can use the query in Pervasive v8.

Comment: What data type is WOBOM_LINE?  What about the parameter you are passing?

Comment: The column name is WOBOM_LINE^ and the data type is Integer. I have that query run on Pervasive v8, but recently update to v10 and it gave me syntax error at WOBOM_LINE^<<???>>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WOBOM_LINE^ is unconventional field name so I have to put double quotes around it